# How can I upload the selected image into the label with using python tkinter?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I can't upload the image into the label, I tried many ways but I always keep getting an error. How can I fix it?
I can open the file and I can select the image but I can't display it on the label

```
def openImageFile():
    global imPath
    imPath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:\\", title = "Open an image", filetypes = (("PNG file","*.png"), ("JPEG File","*.jpeg"), ("JPG File","*.jpg"), ("All File Types","*.*")) )
    return True


def myApp(appName:str, WIDTH:int, HEIGHT:int):
    
    appWin = tk.Tk()
    appWin.title(appName)
    
    appWin.geometry(str(WIDTH)+'x'+str(HEIGHT))
    
    #FRAME
    myFrame = tk.Frame(master = appWin, bg='light gray')
    myFrame.place(relwidth = 0.98, relheight= 0.28, relx = 0.01 ,rely=0.01)
    

    btnUploadImage = tk.Button(myFrame, text="Upload Image", command = lambda: openImageFile() )
    #Butonun uygulama ekranina eklenmesi
    btnUploadImage.place(x=300,y=160)
    
    img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imPath))
    
    #LABEL
    firstName = tk.Label(appWin, bg='light gray', text="First Name").place(x=10,y=40)
    middleName = tk.Label(appWin, bg='light gray', text="Middle Name").place(x=10,y=70)
    surname = tk.Label(appWin, bg='light gray', text="Surname").place(x=10,y=100)
    dateOfBirth = tk.Label(appWin, bg='light gray', text="Date of Birth").place(x=10,y=130)
    photo=tk.Label(appWin, image=img).place(relwidth=0.30,relheight=0.15,x=250,y=40)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few things you are doing wrong. Firstly, the `place` method returns `None` so assigning to a variable has no effect so  `photo=tk.Label (appWin, image=img).place(relwidth=0.30,relheight=0.15,x=250,y=40)` should be

```
photo=tk.Label(appWin, image=img)
photo.place(relwidth=0.30,relheight=0.15,x=250,y=40)
```

in two separate lines. similarly for other variables.

To display the image on the `Label` widget upon uploading, use the `configure` method.

Also place `img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imPath))` in the `openImageFile function` as imPath is not defined until the button is pressed.

Here is the corrected code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog

def openImageFile():
    global img, photo
    imPath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:\\", title = "Open an image", filetypes = (("PNG file","*.png"), ("JPEG File","*.jpeg"), ("JPG File","*.jpg"), ("All File Types","*.*")) )

    if imPath:
        img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imPath))
        photo.configure(image=img)

def myApp(appName:str, WIDTH:int, HEIGHT:int):
    global photo
    appWin = tk.Tk()
    appWin.title(appName)
    
    appWin.geometry(str(WIDTH)+'x'+str(HEIGHT))
    
    #FRAME
    myFrame = tk.Frame(master = appWin, bg='light gray')
    myFrame.place(relwidth = 0.98, relheight= 0.28, relx = 0.01 ,rely=0.01)
    

    btnUploadImage = tk.Button(myFrame, text="Upload Image", command = openImageFile)
    #Butonun uygulama ekranina eklenmesi
    btnUploadImage.place(x=300,y=160)

    #LABEL
    firstName = tk.Label(appWin, bg='light gray', text="First Name").place(x=10,y=40)
    middleName = tk.Label(appWin, bg='light gray', text="Middle Name").place(x=10,y=70)
    surname = tk.Label(appWin, bg='light gray', text="Surname").place(x=10,y=100)
    dateOfBirth = tk.Label(appWin, bg='light gray', text="Date of Birth").place(x=10,y=130)

    photo=tk.Label(appWin)
    photo.place(relwidth=0.30,relheight=0.15,x=250,y=40)

    appWin.mainloop()
    
myApp('hello', 500, 500)
```